# Policy based design: how to customize the Host structure in a proper way?

Tags: c++, templates, strategy-pattern, generic-programming, policy-based-design

I have a bunch of algorithms and collections, and I am using a Policy Based design (see the book [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)) to deal with arbitrary combinatorial complexity. This is great, but in order to prevent the destruction of the Host class by using the pointer to a policy, [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315) suggests to make the destructors of policied protected. However, if I make the Algorithm and Collection destructors protected, I cannot use them on their own, but only as policies. Also, I don't see the benefits of the Policy Based design, compared to a Generic Factory Pattern...

Here is the model of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Collection>
class AlgorithmOne
{
    public: 
        void doSomethingWithData(Collection& data) 
        {
            // Use Collection iterators to build up an algorithm. 
        }
};

template<class Collection>
class AlgorithmTwo
{
    public: 
        void doSomethingWithData(Collection& data) 
        {
            // Use Collection iterators to build up an algorithm. 
        }
};

template<class Collection>
class AlgorithmThree
{
    public: 
        void doSomethingWithData(Collection& data) 
        {
            // Use Collection iterators to build up an algorithm. 
        }
};


template<class Element>
class CollectionOne
{
    public: 
        typedef Element ElementType;

};

template<class Element>
class CollectionTwo
{
    public: 
        typedef Element ElementType;

};

template<class Element>
class CollectionThree
{
    public: 
        typedef Element ElementType;

};

template<typename HostTraits>
class HostInheritsData
:
    public HostTraits::Collection, 
    public HostTraits::Algorithm
{
    public: 
        typedef HostTraits Traits;

        using Traits::Algorithm::doSomethingWithData;

        void doSomethingWithData() 
        {
            doSomethingWithData(*this);
        }
};

template<typename HostTraits>
class HostCompositsData 
:
    public HostTraits::Algorithm
{
    typename HostTraits::Collection data_;

    public: 
        typedef HostTraits Traits;

        using Traits::Algorithm::doSomethingWithData; 

        void doSomethingWithData() 
        {
            doSomethingWithData(data_);
        }

        // Clumsy and breaking encapsulation
        typename HostTraits::Collection& data()
        {
            return data_;
        }
};

template<typename HostTraits>
class GenericStrategy
{
    typename HostTraits::Collection data_; 
    typename HostTraits::Algorithm algorithm_; 

    public: 

        void doSomethingWithData() 
        {
            algorithm_.doSomethingWithData(data_);
        }
};

class ElementOne {}; 
class ElementTwo {}; 
class ElementThree {}; 

struct MyConfig
{
    typedef ElementOne                  Element;
    typedef CollectionThree<Element>      Collection;
    typedef AlgorithmOne<Collection>  Algorithm;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    HostInheritsData<MyConfig> hostInherits;
    hostInherits.doSomethingWithData(); 

    // This must be a mistake, are policies meant to be used this way? 
    hostInherits.doSomethingWithData(hostInherits); 

    HostCompositsData<MyConfig> hostComposits;
    hostComposits.doSomethingWithData(); 

    // Clumsy to use, not intuitive and breaking encapsulation.
    hostComposits.doSomethingWithData(hostComposits.data()); 

    // Combinatorics are there, I can combine whatever I want in MyConfig as for
    // policies, but I can also have global Algorithm and Collection objects 
    // (no protected destructors).
    GenericStrategy<MyConfig> strategy; 
    strategy.doSomethingWithData(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Here are my questions:

I am customizing the structure of a Host class using policies, how can I trully enrich the interface of the Host class, when every realistic Algorithm requires a Collection to work on, and the Collection is encapsulated in the host?

When I compare the Policy Based Design together with a Generic Factory, doesn't the Generic Factory bring me the same combinatorial complexity? It seems that using the Generic Factory is better since I can interchange Element, Container and Algorithm in all possible combinations as well, and I can still have public destructors for all the Policies, which allows me to combine them in any way I want, e.g. a global combination of Element, Collection and Algorithm.

It seems to me that the Enriched Policies become a problem as soon as the structure is customized. Even if I later on add a member function to an algorithm, it will probably have parameters related to Collection (e.g. Collection iterators): if the Host encapsulates Collection using composition, I need to ask it for the parameter of its own member function:

```
// Clumsy to use, not intuitive and breaking encapsulation.
hostComposits.doSomethingWithData(hostComposits.data());
```

and if the Host encapsulates the Collection using inheritance, it gets (to me at least) even weirder:

```
 // This must be a mistake, are policies meant to be used this way? 
    hostInherits.doSomethingWithData(hostInherits);
```

Did I completely misunderstand Policy Based design (yet again), am I using the traits properly? 
Is the Generic Strategy Pattern a better choice in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think carefully about the amount of **coupling** in your design. E.g. make sure that you really want your algorithms to take a `Collection` as template parameters. This introduces a coupling between the algorithm and the container it operates on. Take a look at the Standard Library: its algorithms are **function templates** taking iterators as template parameters. Iterators do not know anyting about the container (Collection in your vocabulary) they point too.

To do other things than iteration and access, algorithms take slightly more enriched types as parameters, e.g. `back_inserters` to accesss the `push_back()` member of a container. But in general -without prior knowledge- there is absolutely no need to pass the entire container interface to all algorithms. To do really container specific things, embedding the algorithm as a **container member function** (e.g. the `sort()` member function of `std::list`) is more appropriate.

For doing slightly different things, there are several overloads (e.g. of `std::transform`) of the same function name. Only if your algorithm needs to **maintain state** is it really necessary to make it a class template, and the preferable way is to make it a **function object**, i.e. containing an overloaded operator(), instead of a `DoSomethingWithData()` member function.

Your data is parameterized in the same way as the Standard Library: a class template with an `Element` as template parameter. The way to feed such data to the algorithms is to provide **iterator access** to your data in the form of `begin()` and `end()` member functions. The Standard containers (`vector`, `map`, `unorderd_map` etc.) also take policies as template parameters, e.g. an `Allocator`, `Compare` or `Hash` class through which you can customize your data's behavior. The Standard smart pointers take a `Deleter` policy parameter to customize their behavior.

**In short**: carefully check your design. What is it that you want to do? What does each component (algorith, data structure) need to know about the other? And can you get there with proper use of the Standard Library? It's a safe bet that most of the things you might want to are already coded in there, and you can concentrate on writing your application's logic, rather than the algorithmic or data structure details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! I have some more questions... Coupling: what happens if I want to specialize an algorithm for a container in a way that I rely on the containers (faster) member function, and not on iterators? If my algorithms take iterators as arguments, this is not possible. I disagree that strong coupling is present here: the algorithms are templated on Containers, what am I coupling them to, Concepts? I am aiming at specialized code, I will have to rely on container member functions for fast operations, there is no way to make the algorithms container-agnostic.

Comment: DoSomethingWithData: of course I won't have this function in the real code; the code above is just a small example, it's only used as a tool to ask the question about policy based design and its use when modifying the structure of the host class.

Comment: To answer your questions: everything I am doing is application logic basically, I am dealing with numerical algorithms on complex data structures. I cannot separate the algorithms form the containers completely for this reason, I will need to rely on container member functions to speed up parts of the algorithms. I will also rely heavily on STL, of course...

Comment: @tomislav-maric Those are all valid points that you make (and which I didn't grasp from your initial question). I rephrased my response in slightly in tone. My main point remains: coupling is something you want to absolutely minimize. E.g. your third point of needing to use one of a data structure's member functions does not mean an algorithm needs to know the rest of the data interface. Many STL algorithms take a function object or predicate as a parameter, and you can use C++11 lambda expressions to pass in data structure member functions.